# comparing these two audio files

Tags: c, audio

i have a two audio files one is original file and another i have corrupted it by reversing some bits, how to compare the quality of these two files is there any algorithm or an software where i can compare the quality of the two files.

Comment: What is quality?  You can compare "quality" by HEARING alone, because quality is a subjective human category.  Also, what in what kind of file: PCM, MP3, what?

Comment: @ Daniel Mošmondor  .MP3 file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`"any algorithm or an software"`: Do you want to program or not?

- If you want a software to do this for you: stackoverflow cannot help you
- If you are willing to program (at least call functions in a library) that's a different story:

There are some libraries which can do this, specifically to convert the audio from compressed to WAVEFORM format in the first place (the library-to-choose depends on which format your audio is in). Or is your audio in waveform format already? you didnt tell. If you have the audio in waveform format (raw audio in e.g. `*` signed 16bit mono at 22khz) you can easily program this yourself: Since the only damage you did to your audio is bitflips you can iterate throught them and just sum the differences up: you have to take in account the format the waveform is in tho: you cannot compare the bit-level (because each bit has different significance); if you have `*` signed 16bit audio you have to use in C the type `int` so that A) the comparison is signed and B) the difference does not overflow.

Comment: Also, you might want to weight this `sum of absolute differences`: If there is a difference of less than 5 in all the signed 16bit values there is no audible difference, on the other hand if there is a difference of 1000 in every 1000th sample that is a very annoying CLICK.

Answer (score 1):

One physical measurement for the quality of sound is the SNR: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signal-to-noise_ratio. I don't know of any lib that does that for you, but it is not to hard to do yourself:

- calculate the noise: noise[n] = manipulated[n] - original[n], n = sample index
- calculate the power of "noise" and of "original": p_noise[n] = noise[n] * noise[n], ...
- get the SNR by dividing the values = SNR[n] = p_original[n]/p_noise[n]

You may want to calculate an average(!) SNR... I hope you can figure out how to do that yourself. This should put your on the right track.